# How to close a SKStoreReview with Detox

Tags: react-native, detox

I am trying to find a solution to close a SKStoreReview popup with Detox. This is only for iOS for rating an app. It gets opened by `react-native-rate` but I cannot find a way to close it.

I wanted to do something like this:

```
await element(by.id('screen')).tapAtPoint({ x: 200, y: 100 });
```

But this is not part of any element.

Do you have any suggestion?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`SKStoreReviewController` renders its view hierarchy out-of-process, and so, Detox cannot interact with it.

Instead, you should mock the API you are using to not actually present it.